# What is the difference between Pathfinder and D&D5e content and availability for French content in France?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, french

I want to start a role-playing game with some friends, with me as the GM. I already practiced with another GM on an introductory game called *Chroniques Oubliés* (Forgotten Chronicles), with simplified D&D 3.5e rules.

I know that Pathfinder and D&D 5e are the most popular systems, and I want to pick one of those two. I already read a lot about the difference between them (mostly on an English website), but I want to know if there is a major difference in content regarding French language between those two games. Does one have more campaigns in French? A better translation? A better distribution in France?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

French player here.

### Online resources

Pathfinder being older, most of its wiki has been translated to French. You can find it at [www.pathfinder-fr.org](http://www.pathfinder-fr.org). Some entries are poorly translated or missing but they're very rare.

As of now, I've yet to find a good site with a D&D 5e translation.  There is also less content published, so the percentage of translation may be higher.

Blake Steel suggested this [search in dmsguild, filtered by language](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_0_0_0_0_0_45479).

### Books and availability

All base books of Pathfinder have also been fully released by Paizo in French, as well as most Adventure Paths, and can be found in your local (well-furnished) game store (thanks @BlakeSteel for the reminder. List includes but is not restricted to: Core rulebook, Gamemastering book, All bestiaries, most extensions and all AP i know off)

The base book for D&D 5e can also be found, and are just as available, if not slightly more (by a short margin - You can also find D&D 5e in general bookstore chains, such as La Fnac, to name one. P&P RPG being popularized, they try to have some rulebooks, and the most famous is obviously D&D5e. You won't find any extensions, though, you will have to go to a specialized seller).

Thanks to Blake Steel for the list of [5e localized products announcements](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/localization).

Since you were starting, I pointed first at online resources, assuming you would not invest just yet.

#### Conclusion

Overall, out of experience, Pathfinder is more easily available than 5e in France, and you can find more translated content, just because it's older (and therefore, translators have had more time). Easiest (and cheapest) way is online, you'll have to order or find a good game shop if you want to invest in physical copies.

Comment: WotC announced [localized products](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/localization), have they not made it to France?

Comment: It does appear that some content may have been officially released by WoTC in French. Addressing this would be helpful.

Comment: The last paragraph may be ill-phrased, but the base book have indeed been released by WotC. I'll clarify this part later. Also, given the comments on Blake Steel's answer, I'll provide some more information regarding 5e to make for a more complete answer. (Later, can't right now)

Comment: Perhaps include [this search of the dmsguild](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_0_0_0_0_0_45479) and the [5e localized products announcement](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/localization)  to address 5e content.

Comment: @BlakeSteel Here, done, nice and complete answer. Thanks!

Comment: As of now, this answer is still relevant. For future readers, you might want to complete your answer with [aidedd](https://www.aidedd.org/) where a lot of basic rules are available in french (even some of the XGtE) and also a link to [Black Book Edition site](https://www.black-book-editions.fr/) as they are official french translators and editors for 5e (fun fact, they're also the creators of *Chroniques Oubliées* which the OP mentioned)